# NEXT Keyword not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms, mobilestudio

I have created two SMS messages in Mobile Studio, I have sent out SMS1 which has a NEXT KEYWORD configured, my second SMS, (lets call it SMS2) is setup as a Response SMS, so it triggers when the NEXT keyword is used or if the message is prefixed with whatever the keyword is.

SMS2 isn't triggered when I respond to SMS1, but does work if I manually prefix my SMS with the next keyword.

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: I just tested this setup and it works as expected. I created a textresponse and assigned it to keyword EZ1 then I created an outbound message and set next keyword to be EZ1, I sent the message and when I received the message I responded "Hey" and then I got the expected text response. Did you respond within the hour of the outbound message?

Comment: I sent the response within 15mins, not sure what the issue is.